# Searching in:all with includeSpamTrash=false returns spam and trash

Tags: gmail-api

When searching threads.list with q="in:all" and includeSpamTrash="false" the api still returns messages that are in spam and in trash. Is this the expected behaviour and if so how would I get in:all without the spam and trash messages?

Comment: "in:all" is the default behavior, so just don't specify a "q" param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried excluding threads with the label "Trash"?

In the UI, for example, I would use:

`in: all -label:"Trash"`